# problem while encoding string to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am gettting problem while encoding string R.F.< 1 into Xml

i am using `node.innerxml=string;`

it shows exeption name cannot start with 1 or hexadecimal value 0x33.....

pls help me to solve this

Comment: You are not encoding the string. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When encoding to XML you need to consider reserved XML characters, and encode them accordingly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Answer (score 1):

The `InnerXml` property of an `XmlNode` instance accepts only well-formed XML text. Whenever you attempt to apply the string `R.F.< 1`, the less-than character is being interpreted as the beginning of an XML element tag. Since an element name cannot begin with a digit, the XML is deemed not to be well-formed, and the set operation fails.

If you wish to put arbitrary text inside an XmlNode, then you should use the `InnerText` property rather than the `InnerXml` property. This will ensure that the less-than character is properly escaped (`R.F.&lt; 1`) in the resulting XML document.